# Combine multiple different rows to make single row by converting rows to column attributes

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, phpmyadmin, left-join

[image: Here is the mysql output]

I am joining 3 tables to get the desire result, but for one user I am getting 4 rows(only two column attributes are changed, all other attributes are same for one particular user).

**My required output**
I want to get single row which contains different rows attributes as separate columns instead of different attributes in 4 different rows.

Here is my current Query

```
SELECT
CONCAT(
    'https://example.com/?search=',
    comment_content
) AS link,
wp_comments.user_id,
user_email,
user_login,
user_nicename,
comment_date as 'Interview Date',
display_name,
user_registered,
meta_key,
meta_value
```

Comment: are there a fixed number of meta keys, so search for mysqlm pivot, if there could be more look for mysql dynamic pivot

Comment: Yes, there are only 4 meta keys

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) [mre]

Comment: Please either ask about 1 bad query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about the former 1st because misconceptions in the former will get in the way of understanding the latter. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do. [ask] [Help] Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to GROUP BY the column that are always the same.

The rest is a aggregation function with a condothion

It is called pivot or oivting

```
SELECT
CONCAT(
    'https://example.com/?search=',
    comment_content
) AS link,
wp_comments.user_id,
user_email,
user_login,
user_nicename,
comment_date as 'Interview Date',
display_name,
user_registered,
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'first_name' THEN meta_value END) as 'first_name', 
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'last_name' THEN meta_value END) as 'last_name', 
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'user_birthday' THEN meta_value END) as 'user_brthday' 
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'user_sex' THEN meta_value END) as 'user_sex' 
FROM ...
WHERE ....
GROUP BY link,wp_comments.user_id,
user_email,
user_login,
user_nicename,
`Interview Date`,
display_name,
user_registered
```